# Azure Service Fabric - Debug with Symbols

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Is there a way to get the Symbol files for the Azure Service Fabric libraries like [Microsoft.ServiceFabric](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ServiceFabric/)

Comment: sorry the description of the link should be : Microsoft.ServiceFabric (ref to https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ServiceFabric/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around that - using [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), to exported the pdb files. :)

Answer (score 0):

The Service Fabric (including the SDK) is not Open Source (yet), so therefor the symbol files (PDBs) are not provided as they are primarily intended for debugging.